# How to merge two SQL server tables based on a condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server

What I am trying to do is kind of like a `Join`, but I want the data from a table to actually be merged with data from another.

To make this more clear I will go a bit in-depth with explaining the problem, as at its current form, my explanation sounds rather stupid.

The first table is **dbo.Categories** which has columns like `[Id], [Name_Good]`.

The second table is **dbo.Categories_Title** containing columns like `[Id], [Name], [Title_OK]`.

What I would like to do is merge the two tables `on Categories.[Name_Good] = Categories_Title.[Name]`.

so **dbo.Categories** will also have `[Title_OK]` column from the other table, as well as the correct values corresponding the condition that.

The resulting dbo.Categories table should, therefore, contain `[Id], [Name_Good,[Title_OK]`.

```
INSERT Categories (Title_OK)
SELECT Title_Ok
FROM Categories_Title
WHERE Categories.Name_Good=Categories_Title.Name
```

I tried out using this code but I am getting the following error:

> Invalid column name 'Title_OK'

Comment: Do you actually want to *add a new column* in `Categories`? Or are you looking for a SQL query that will just *display* the expected results?

Comment: I actually want to add a new column.

Comment: If you are already having records in Category table, you should use update command. But before it, you must have that new column in DB (add it first then use update command)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to first alter the `Categories` table and add a `Title_Ok` column:

```
ALTER TABLE Categories ADD Title_Ok VARCHAR(MAX);
```

After this, you should be doing an *update* here, not an insert:

```
UPDATE c
SET c.Title_Ok = ct.Title_Ok
FROM Categories c
INNER JOIN Categories_Title ct
    ON c.Name_Good = ct.Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

First is to add Title_Ok Column in Categories  table

```
ALTER TABLE Categories ADD Title_Ok VARCHAR(MAX);
```

Second is to insert records in Categories table from Categories_Title

```
INSERT INTO Categories ( [Id], [Name_Good], [Title_OK])
SELECT  [Id], [Name], [Title_OK] FROM  Categories_Title
```